# Invalid version string "*"

Tags: php, composer-php

Here is the line that causes the issue:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "ext-calendar": "*"
    }
},
```

And on `composer update` it results in a `Invalid version string "*"`

Composer version: `1.9.3`

Tried to remove the `vendor` and re-install everything, but same results.

Comment: Why not specify a version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your composer.json, you can add platform into your config, to force it to resolve dependencies to a specific version of PHP.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    },
},
```

You use this platform key if for example your dev machine has a different version of PHP than your actual server, so that composer resolves the dependencies to the specific version. This means having `*` in here doesn't make sense. Also, that's a PHP extension, not a PHP version, so it just belongs in the normal require section, where a `*` is accepted.

Either delete that section, or lock down an actual PHP number, and you should be good to go.